# How to use Back-to-app button on iOS10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10, back-button

In iOS 9, we have Back-to-appB button in application A when the application A is opened from application B. You can see Back-to-app button (Back to Safari, Back to App Store) in below picture: 
[Example pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58xa1.png)

But on iOS 10, we haven't seen Back-to-app button in status bar.
So could you please tell me how to enable this button on iOS 10 and how to use it in coding.
I'm using Objective-C language.

**Updated:**

I saw Back-to-App button on status bar, but I want to know how to call action of Back-to-App button without touching. We want to use this function to replace OpenURL method. With this way, we can open Safari browser without reloading page.

Comment: Can you please post a minimal (code) example that shows the issue?

Comment: @shallowThought: Currently, I updated my question, thank you for your attention

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: I had solution but this solution infringe police of AppStore. Therefore, we cannot publish application onto AppStore.

Comment: Hi, I am facing same issue. Going back to safari without opening a new tab. Any progress on this?

Answer (score 2):

This feature is also work in iOS10, if your destination application open from source application then this option will visible in status bar.

For Example, your demo app contain url schema like "demo",
and you open you demo app through safari like "demo://" then you can see the "< Safari" button in your demo app status bar.

Comment: Thank you, I saw Back-to-App button on status bar. Do you know how to call action of Back-to-App button without touching

Comment: i think this is not possible. we can not open app without user interaction.

Comment: We try to investigate this problem, because we don't want to reload page when opening Safari browser. We can use private API from apple but to do this, we have to jaibreak device -> This isn't allow. This problem is very difficult to do

Answer (score 1):

Deep linking of application A works if the user moves to application B by tapping on link or button from application A.

On the contrary it will not work if you press home button and move to another application.

Comment: it's mean you want to use URLScheme in here, right?

Comment: Application A is my app, application B is Safari browser. We want to use Back-to-app button to avoid to reload page in Safari browser, this is really our problem. If you can, please suggest to our, thanks